# How to show icon of apk in my File manager

Tags: android, icons, apk

I want to show icon of apk file in my listview.

How can i get icon of apk?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

```
    if (file.getPath().endsWith(".apk")) {
        String filePath = file.getPath();
        PackageInfo packageInfo = context.getPackageManager().getPackageArchiveInfo(filePath, PackageManager.GET_ACTIVITIES);
        if(packageInfo != null) {
            ApplicationInfo appInfo = packageInfo.applicationInfo;
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 8) {
                appInfo.sourceDir = filePath;
                appInfo.publicSourceDir = filePath;
            }
            Drawable icon = appInfo.loadIcon(context.getPackageManager());
            bmpIcon = ((BitmapDrawable) icon).getBitmap();
        }
    }
```

The most important line is `appInfo.publicSourceDir = filePath;`

This is a bug. See http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=9151

The null check `packageInfo != null` is there in case the .apk is not parsed correctly.

Comment: This should be accepted as the correct answer as the solution proposed by Varundroid does NOT work with non-installed apk-files.

Comment: @Jens totally agree with you. Best answer should always be accepted. I edited my answer. Thanks for pointing the issue. Cheers.