# Get icon of application on sdcard

Tags: android, icons, nullpointerexception, android-package-managers

Hi I have an application on my sd (not installed just stored there) how can I get information about it by just giving the path to the application. For instance I have pandora.apk sitting in my downloads folder so the path is /sdcard/download/pandora.apk knowing that path how can i get the icon of it. Thanks for any help

I've tried this code but get a nullpointerexception

```
final PackageManager pm = context.getPackageManager();
PackageInfo packageInfo = pm.getPackageArchiveInfo("/sdcard/download/pandora.apk", 0);
Drawable icOn = packageInfo.applicationInfo.loadIcon(context.getPackageManager());
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Its already answered here. [How to show icon of apk in my File manager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5674683/how-to-show-icon-of-apk-in-my-file-manager)

```
if (file.getPath().endsWith(".apk")) {
String filePath = file.getPath();
PackageInfo packageInfo = context.getPackageManager().getPackageArchiveInfo(filePath, PackageManager.GET_ACTIVITIES);
ApplicationInfo appInfo = packageInfo.applicationInfo;
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 8) {
    appInfo.sourceDir = filePath;
    appInfo.publicSourceDir = filePath;
}
Drawable icon = appInfo.loadIcon(context.getPackageManager());
bmpIcon = ((BitmapDrawable) icon).getBitmap();
}
```

Comment: thanks sorry about the duplicate i searched but couldn't find what i was looking for guess i just didn't search well :)